# How to validate input type="number" in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, reactjs

I have a problem with validation of HTML element **input type="number"** in **ReactJS** Application:

```
render() {
    return (
        <input type="number" onBlur={this.onBlur} />
    );
},

onBlur(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

**The log is:**

[image]

Everything is ok on desktop application, but on mobile there is a problem.
User can change the keyboard and enter everything he wants.
So I wanted to fix it using validation. When I try to catch the value the user enter, I get this log. It's like React is just hiding this incorrect value.

How can I fix it?
Or there is another way how to validate **input type="number"** in **ReactJS** Application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the best way how to validate:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

In this way I can't enter smth else. Moreover **e.target.value** with checking on **null** can't get good fixed result because empty field and the field with not correct text are the same (empty).

Comment: "pattern: This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email or password; otherwise it is ignored" via MDN

Answer (score 2):

You can access the value through:

```
e.target.value;
```

I don't recall if on mobile if it passes an empty value if it's not a number like on desktop. But just do your checks against it. Don't let the form submit unless it's all valid :)

Comment: You can see from my screenshot, that e.target is null, so I can't get it.

Comment: Ah my bad. Typically one will update the stored value on a keyup change. Then you have a button to confirm the input.

Comment: I don't want to check in method onChange. By the way, onChange the same empty value like in onBlur

Comment: If you set a ref on the element: `ref="myNumber"` or w/e you wanna call it. You can access it through: `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myNumber)`. Should be able to access the value attribute from there.

Comment: With what value in the field though? Is it a number?

Comment: If it's a number, I can catch it in onChange and onBlur. But if I try to enter some letter into input type=number, I can't catch it in these methods. I see the letter in the field, but not in the functions.

Comment: The field is likely reporting null for a value then. Test against null for your validation.

Comment: It's a good idea. If a have valid data, I have or some number or empty, if not valid - null. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't help because empty field and not corrected answer are the same empty result. Anyway, thanks.